# Splitting two merged floating point numbers using sed/awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have sequences appearing in a file as

```
2282.641.33712e+06
```

which I want to split into the respective floating point numbers as

```
2282.64 and 1.33712e+06.
```

The floating point number with the e+06
contains a single leading digit before the decimal.

Could this be done with sed / awk ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `sed` one-liner might do the trick:

```
sed 's/[0-9]\.[0-9]/ &/2' file
```

or by matching only the dots:

```
sed 's/.\./ &/2' file
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It does the job.

Comment: Many thanks for the edited answer. Could you perhaps elaborate on what &/2 does ?

Comment: @Thejas `&` references the whole matched portion of the pattern space (matching `[0-9]\.[0-9]` in the first `sed` and `.\.` in the second `sed`).  `2` only replaces the second match.

Comment: @Thejas You may consider reading [The s Command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command) in [GNU sed Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html). Beware that GNU sed has extensions to the POSIX sed.

Comment: Many thanks Nejat. Makes perfect sense. Will go through the manual.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way. Requires [gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk) for the [`gensub` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-gensub_0028_0029-function-_0028gawk_0029-1)

```bash
gawk 'BEGIN {
    a = "2282.641.33712e+06"
    separated = gensub("(\\.[0-9]+)([0-9]\\.)", "\\1,\\2", "g", a)
    n = split(separated, nums, ",")
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print nums[i]
}'
```

```
2282.64
1.33712e+06
```

That looks for a dot followed by some digits followed by a digit followed by a dot, then inserts a comma in the appropriate place.

Comment: Thanks for this answer as well. It works well, though a bit longer.